# How to get the value of more than one attribute of element in JavaScript dom via loop

Tags: javascript

how I can get the list value of all attribute from HTML evlemnt via loop 
now from my code i have three attr i want obtain the value of all three attr in one list via loop how i can do it ? example:

```
 f1="hi" 
 f2=" how" 
 f3=" are" 
 f4="you"
```

in button Element i want get all of them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("target");

for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
  var attrib = elem.attributes[i];
  alert(attrib.name + " = " + attrib.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.attributes`

```js
    function returnAttributes(el)
    {
       return Array.prototype.map.call(el.attributes, function(obj){
           return [obj.name, obj.value];
       }).sort(function(a, b){
           return a[0]-b[0] || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
       }).map(function(a){return a[1];}).join(" ");
    }


document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var attr = returnAttributes(document.querySelector("button"));
  alert(attr);
}, false);
```

```html
<button f1="How" f2="are" f3="you" f4="doing?" >Test</button>
```

It looks like magic, but it simply does the following:

`Element.attributes` is an arrayish object. We can loop it by using `Array.prototype.map.call`. `Map` walks over all elements an performs an action on them. In this case return the array with array object containing the attribute's `name` and `value`. We then sort the array alphabetically using sort. We sort on the attribute's name. We don't want to return the attribute's name, so we walk over the array once more using `map`. Now only returning the values. Finally we return the values in a string by using `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
function getValues() {
    var yourElement = document.getElementById("your_element_id");
    var valueArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < yourElement.attributes.length; i++) {
        vauleArray.push(yourElement.attributes[i].value);
    }
}
```